# Base64 encoding and decoding works on Android, but not on online converters

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm encoding a Bitmap to a Base64 String to send to an API, but I get a `500` because it isn't being encoded properly. But when I decode the `Base64 String` back to a `Bitmap`, it displays properly.

Also, when I copy the encoded string and try to decode using an online converter, it doesn't work. Almost like the encoding and decoding work only on Android.

When I use an online converter to decode the image and send it to the API, it works perfectly.

[link to raw image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2RbV.png)

```
fun convertBase64ToImage(base46String: String): Bitmap {
    val stuff = Base64.decode(base46String, Base64.DEFAULT)
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stuff, 0, stuff.size)
}

fun convertImageToBase64(image: Bitmap): String {
    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, IMAGE_QUALITY, byteArrayOutputStream)
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```

**online converter's Base64 String =>** `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`

**Base64 String generated on Android =>** `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`

**when I change the compressFormat from JPEG to PNG I get this** => `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`

Comment: Can you post an example of what you get encoding on Android, and what you get encoding via a specific online converter? Any differences are likely due to you hardcoding the JPEG format, or setting a different `IMAGE_QUALITY` to the online converter.

Comment: @JakeSteam I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you add the raw image too?